# Weight of Vectors - doc2vec

Tags: nlp

Let's assume I have a number of different documents. I used `doc2vec` to generate a vector per document. So after plotting it with `t-Sne`, I can visualize where the documents are in a $2$ or $3$ dimensional space. So I have realistic distances between the documents.

Now there comes the (for me) tricky part:
I want consumers to answer a questionnaire, where they rate the documents on a $5$-point-Lickert scale ($1$ do not like - $5$ like very much). In the end, I want to see where consumer positions himself in the plot I made before.

Which means, that I somehow need to weight the vectors. 
document $1$ - with vector $1234$ is rated as $5$ (so this document has a high (I call it) "gravitation" )
document $2$ - with vector $1756$ is rated with $2$ (so with lower gravity...)

Do you have any suggestion on how to solve this problem? I am still not sure on how to "calculate" with (let's say a $100$ dimensional) vector

It would be awesome if you had a hint for me.